# how to prove A heap of  keys is an array  equivalent to balanced binary tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

how can I prove the following sentence?
A heap of  keys is an array  equivalent to balanced binary tree (leaves’ depth differs by at moat 1). Depth is Θ(log⁡ )

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you facing an issue?

Comment: It looks like you have a (slightly badly worded and ambiguous) definition of a heap, but what specifically would you like an answer to say about this sentence?

Answer (score -1):

The statement is not entirely true because:

- *"A heap of  keys **is** an array "*: A heap is *not* necessarily implemented using an array. This should be rephrased.
- *"to balanced **binary** tree"*: this is only true for a [*binary* heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap). There are d-ary heaps.
- ["equivalent"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) means the statement works in both directions, but a balanced binary tree is not guaranteed to correspond to a binary heap.

I would suggest a statement like this:

> A **binary** heap of  keys -- as **can be implemented** by an array  of size  -- **represents** a balanced binary tree, whose leaves’ depths differ by at most 1 and that depth is Θ(log⁡).

This is a true statement, because a binary heap is by *definition* a *complete* binary tree, as stated [in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap):

> Shape property: a binary heap is a *complete binary tree*; that is, all levels of the tree, except possibly the last one (deepest) are fully filled, and, if the last level of the tree is not complete, the nodes of that level are filled from left to right.

This property already says the binary heap is a binary tree with its leaves at the bottom level, and possibly some at the level above it. That means the maximum difference in depths of the leaves is 1.

Given a binary heap with  keys, the first (root) level will have 1 key, the second level will have 2 keys, the third level will have 4 keys,... etc, each time doubling, until all keys are distributed, and so the last level may have a number of nodes that is not a power of 2.

If we number the keys in level order, starting with 1, then the left-most node at the second level will have number 2, the left-most node at the third level will have number 4,... etc, each time the next power of 2, so that the left most node at level  (starting from zero) has number 2. The left most node at the *bottom* level will have a number 2, such that ⁡/2 < 2 ≤ ⁡

The depth of that node on the bottom level is thus , which (given the above range for 2) is O(log).

Note that the fact that the binary heap can be nicely represented as an array , is not really relevant, as the property of *complete* binary tree is already present in the definition of a binary heap.